# In Python, what's the best way for me to write reusable code that provides me methods for interacting with a list of objects?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I'm not quite sure how to ask this question, let alone find the answer, partially because I may be completely wrong in my approach to solving this problem.

I'm writing some Python, and I have a class (`Users`) which is basically used to instantiate a number of objects of a particular type (`User`), and then provide a number of methods to help me work with those objects in a more straightforward manner. The code I have looks like this:

```
from defusedxml.ElementTree import parse

class Users:

    def __init__(self, path):

        self.path = path
        self.users = []

        users = parse(path).getroot()

        for user in users:
            u = User.user_from_xml(user)
            self.users.append(u)

    def __iter__(self):

        self.i = 0
        return self

    def __next__(self):

        if self.i < len(self.users):
            self.i += 1
            return self.users[(self.i - 1)]
        else:
            raise StopIteration

    def get_user_by_id(self, user_id):
        return next((user for user in self.users if user.id == user_id), None)

    def search_attribute(self, attribute, value):

        return [user for user in self.users if
            getattr(user, attribute, None) != None and
            value.lower() in str(getattr(user, attribute).lower())]



class User:

    def __init__(self, user_id, username, email, first_name, last_name):

        self.id = int(user_id)
        self.username = username
        self.email = email
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name

    def __repr__(self):

        if self.first_name == None or self.last_name == None:
            return "%s (User Id: %s)" % (self.username, self.id)

        return "%s %s (%s)" % (self.first_name, self.last_name, self.username)

    @staticmethod
    def user_from_xml(user):

        return User(
            user.get("id"),
            element.find("username").text,
            element.find("email").text,
            element.find("firstname").text,
            element.find("lastname").text
        )
```

I have a number of other objects stored in XML in a similar way - for example, `Events`. I can see the need to use the same methods defined in `Users`, with the only real difference being the type of object contained in the list created in `__init__`.

So the question is: **what's the best way for me to make this code reuseable, while maintaining readability, etc.?** Or maybe I'm on completely the wrong track.

Comment: Are you saying ONLY the constructor changes between User, Events, etc.?

Comment: whatever you do, `Users` should almost certainly not be an iterator, either define you own class or make `__iter__` a generator function. Or looking at your `__iter__` and `__next__` implementations, just do `def __iter__(self): return iter(self.users)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these class methods will truly be identical, I think the simplest method would be to just make a more generic class to replace `Users` that takes another class (e.g., `User` or `Event`) as an argument in its `__init__` method. Your class might look like so:

```
class Things(object):

    def __init__(self, PATH, Thing): #Thing is a class

        self.PATH = PATH
        self.users = []

        users = parse(PATH).getroot()

        for thing in things:
            t = Thing.thing_from_xml(thing)
            self.things.append(t)

    def methods...
```

A more robust/scalable solution might be to use inheritance.

You could create an abstract base class that has all of your methods, and then override the base class's `__init__` method within each child class. I'll draw out an example of this:

```
class AbstractBaseClass(object):

    def __init__(self, PATH):
        self.PATH = PATH
        self.things = []

    def methods...



class Users(AbstractBaseClass):

    def __init__(self, PATH):
        super(Users, self).__init__() # calls the parent __init__ method

        users = parse(PATH).getroot()

        for user in users:
            u = User.user_from_xml(user)
            self.things.append(u)


    #no need to define methods, as they were already defined in parent class
    #but you can override methods or add new ones if you want
```

Your `Events` class would also inherit `AbstractBaseClass` and thereby have all of the same methods of `Users`. You should read up on inheritance, it's a great tool.

EDIT TO ADDRESS YOUR COMMENT:

Properties might be a good way to get that attribute `users` back into to your `Users` class. Change `things` to `_things` to suggest that it is private, and then create a `users` property, like so:

```
class Users(AbstractBaseClass):

    @property
    def users(self):
        return self._things
```

This way you can call `Users.users` and get `Users._things`.

If you really, really care about code reuse, you could even do something dynamic like this in `__init__`:

```
class AbstractBaseClass(object):

    def __init__(self, PATH):
        self._things = []
        self.PATH = PATH

        setattr(self, self.__class__.__name__.lower(), self._things)
        #This creates an attribute that is the lowercase version of the
        #class name and assigns self._things to it
```

Note: I think this is a little ugly and unnecessary. Also, since you would have two attributes that are the same thing - it might lead to your object being in an incoherent state.

That said, to me `Users.users` seems redundant. I'm not fully aware of the context of your problem but I think I would prefer to have my `Users` objects simply behave like the list `users`, but with extra methods (those you defined).

In `AbstractBaseClass` you could define `__iter__` to be the `__iter__` of the `_things` attribute.

```
class AbstractBaseClass(object):

    def __init__(self, PATH):
        self._things = []
        self.PATH = PATH

    def __iter__(self):
        return self._things.__iter__()

    #You might also want this - it lets you do list-like indexing
    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return self._things.__getitem__(i)
```

I think the above does essentially what you were doing with `__iter__` and `__next__` in your original code, but in a cleaner way. This way, you don't have to access `_things` or `users` directly to play with a list of your user objects; you can play with a list of users through your `Users` class, which, by its name, seems like the purpose of the class.

Comment: I was thinking about inheritance as well, but the thing that I don't like is that I'll end up with `Users.things` rather than `Users.users` - in other words, the name of the list does not really describe what it contains. That can probably be inferred by the name of the class inheriting the base class; but still not ideal.

Both are better solutions than what I've written so far, though.

Comment: @JamesLambeth, I edited my answer to address your comment

Comment: You make an excellent point about treating the `Users` class more like the `users` list; rather than necessarily exposing `User.things` or `User.users`. I like this approach! Thanks.